# iOS Button to call

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Sorry for bad English

In FirstViewController.h I wrote:

```
 - (IBAction)goToURL:(id)sender;
```

in FirstViewController.m I wrote:

```
- (IBAction)goToURL:(id)sender;
{
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://01999999999"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];

}
```

I added a button as you can see in the picture.
http://url.bg/show-image.php?id=683e9491d40e684f2eaefdbe19fe1b45

The problem is that the simulator is not giving me an error, I know wrong somewhere?

Comment: Why do you want to get an error? If there's no error then that's a good thing...

Comment: @edc1591 not necessarily, not getting any error from something that's not working correctly is like hell

Comment: @Carlo True, but in this case it's just two lines of code...

Comment: @edc1591 haha I guess you're right, but if you don't know what's going on (see answer below, I didn't know that =P) it can still be a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 6):

That code will not do anything in the simulator because the simulator doesn't have a Phone app. You'll need to test that on an actual iPhone.

EDIT: There's also a syntax error in your .m file. I'm assuming that you just made that error typing the question because I don't think it would compile. Anyway, you shouldn't have a semicolon before the first curly bracket. Like so;

```
- (IBAction)goToURL:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://01999999999"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
}
```